# Reduction mod p

Tags: number-theory

I have seen in the books how to reduce curve modulo $p$ when it has integer coefficients. How can one do it in case when it has rational coefficients? Should, for example, 1/25 go to infinity in reduction modulo 5?

What is the definition of a good reduction of a curve $y^2=f(x)$ when $f$ has rational coefficients? Maybe that p does not divide numerator of discriminant of $f$, since it doesn't have to be integer number.

I would appreciate any help.